# Trouble trying to access KVM code in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04, virtualization, kvm

My virtualization project requires me to make changes in the vmx.c file of KVM.I have installed KVM in my Ubuntu 14.04 OS and am done launching an instance too.Yet,when I look up for vmx.c in the system,I do not find it.I though find a vmx.h file in the following directory /usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-30/arch/x86/include/asm.It would be really helpful if someone could guide me as to how do I go about it.Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to modify KVM without recompiling all the kernel, you can use Jan Kiszka's repo for building an external KVM module as following:

```
git clone git://git.kiszka.org/kvm-kmod.git
cd kvm-kmod
git submodule update --init
./configure
make sync
make
```

You can find after that the files you need in `kvm-kmod/x86/` and you can modify them as you need.
To install your modified version you can use run from the `kvm-mod` directory:

```
    make
    sudo su
    rmmod kvm-intel
    rmmod kvm
    insmod kvm
    insmod kvm-intel
```

You can put these commands in a script file to avoid typing them each time ;)

Comment: is there a way so it builds to the path /dev/kvm?

Comment: What I wrote in my response does exactly this, but you need to insert modified version after each boot