# Build KVM from source

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu, kvm

I got kvm source using `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/virt/kvm/kvm.git`.

I want to play around with the kvm core in order to add and/or remove features and each build to check certain VMs under kvm.

I haven't found any info on how to do it appropriately - the installation and the un-installation of kvm. (All installation related answers are using "apt-get install" and all uninstallation are using "apt-get purge", which doesn't help with building from source).

Anyone knows how to do this appropriately? or can reference me to a helpful source?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine), KVM is a part of the Linux kernel, transforming the OS into a hypervisor. It cannot be run without using Linux. Indeed, the tree you are referring to is a Linux kernel. You'd need to configure the kernel (enabling KVM), build and install it.

If you look for a stand-alone codebase, you can refer to the [Xen](https://www.xenproject.org/) or the [Jailhouse](https://github.com/siemens/jailhouse) hypervisors. Note that Linux is mandatory for Jailhouse. For Xen, instead, there are more options for the Dom0 OS.

Comment: Well, never played with linux kernels.
If I want to proceed with KVM, I should install new kernel each build?
Will my other files be saved (on file system)

Comment: Most Linux distributions likely have KVM support compiled. So, rather than trying to compile it, you should look for configuring/enabling it.

Comment: Building and installing a kernel doesn't affect the rest of the system.

Comment: Of course. But no reason to build a new kernel if the one installed already supports KVM.

Comment: You can play with KVM and modify its source without recompiling your whole kernel. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384340/trouble-trying-to-access-kvm-code-in-ubuntu-14-04/33409122#33409122